# how to put a white background in iOS against a view

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7

I have a view in iOS where I wish to have a white rectangle background (with curved corners) similar to the one which is in the pic below. Could anyone please help me as how to achieve this in iOS

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the controller's view to the blue background. Then you'll add a new subview that has a white background with the corner radius desired:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UIView *roundedBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 280)];
[roundedBox setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[roundedBox.layer setCornerRadius:10];
[self.view addSubview:roundedBox];
```

You'll need to make sure you import QuartzCore, since it is required to manipulate layers directly, which is how you set the corner radius:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: Thanks hukir. I am albe to add the blue rounded box. But the button and the label disappears. Can you help me as how to place them in subview

Comment: I got it. What I need to do is add the statement [self.view addSubview:label]; after the code giving by hukir. Thanks Hukir

Answer (score 0):

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
view.layer.maskToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe this will set the entire background color to white. Is there a controller available to accomplish this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A more difficult but more powerful way to do this is [bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cornerRadius](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html). You will have to create a new UIView. Personally I would subclass UIView, and after you've created it, add something like:

```
UIBezierPath *roundedCornerRectangle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:10]; // create bezier path
UIRectFill(self.bounds); // initialize rectangle onto view, will appear with default settings which is a black rectangle
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill]; // set color to white
[roundedCornerRectangle fill]; // fill rectangle with color
[self drawShape];
```

Comment: Can this be achieved by container view?

Comment: Will UIBezierPath holds other views like button and label. Please let me know